# AutoMapper - Mapping to existing model with child collection from a ViewModel with child collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

```
//entities
class Order
    int Id
datetime OrderDate 
string SomeOtherOrderProp // I dont need to update but it has a value
    List<Detail> Details

class Detail
    int Id 
    decimal Quantity
string SomeOtherDetailProp // I dont need to update but it has a value

//DTO's
class OrderDTO
    int Id
datetime OrderDate
    List<DetailDTO> DetailsDTO

class DetailDTO
    int Id
    decimal Quantity
```

I need to map from OrderDTO to an existing order.

For that I have a couple of mappings defined:

```
        CreateMap<OrderDTO, Order>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Details, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DetailsDTO))

        CreateMap<DetailDTO, Detail>()
```

I then get my existing order.

```
var order = GetOrderById(int id);
```

Finally when I do

```
_mapper.Map(orderDto, order),
```

to transfer all orderDTO properties to my existing order properties, it does so fine.

OrderDto.Id gets mapped to Order.Id.

OrderDTO.OrderDate to Order.OrderDate,

and it retains the original value of Order.SomeOtherOrderProp property, which is what I want and expect.

However, the child collections property, Details SomeOtherDetailProp, doesn't retain its value.
For example, Detail.SomeOtherDetailProp would get its existing value set to null, because my DetailDTO, did not have that property.

**Question:**
For the top level object it retained the SomeOtherOrderProp, but in the child collection it overwrote SomeOtherDetailProp. What do I need to do so it retains SomeOtherDetailProp's original value?

Comment: When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. If this is not what you want, take a look at AutoMapper.Collection.